# How to customize short preview of notifications in iOS 10+

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios-app-extension

I have implemented iOS rich notifications in my app based on [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH16-SW1).

I watched WWDC [Introduction to Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707/), [Advanced Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/), and [Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/708/), and read [`UNNotificationContentExtension`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension). All of these show that I can implement Notification Content extension to customize notification presentation. But to me it seems that they all assume that we can customize only the expanded view (the view that opens up when we 3D press the short preview).

Now I know that I can customize the presentation of the short preview in a very restricted way - using title/body I can decide if I want a bold or normal font; by using [Notification Service extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH16-SW1) I can add a media preview. However, **what I need is to be able to build the UI of this short preview myself** - add custom `UIImageView`, etc. Right now it seems that this is not possible, but I wasn't able to find any explicit information that would confirm it.

So my question is: Can we customize the short preview of a notification? If not, is there any explicit statement in official docs that explain this? If yes, can you refer me to some docs/tutorials on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled upon the following line in the *Customizing the Appearance of Notifications* [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications) in the official documentation:

> The system provides the interface for the abbreviated banner, but you can customize the full interface using a notification content app extension.

This confirms that currently there is no way of customizing the short preview ("abbreviated banner" in the docs).

Answer (score 0):

I think (I'm not 100% sure) that you can only display an `Attachment Image` in the Notification banner, because you don't have Storyboad or UI file for this. It is the default Notification banner design.

You can follow this great guide (links below), it helps me understand `Notification Content Extension` and `Notification Service Extension` and all the logic behind and how it really works.

You can try to make some adjustments to the project, trying with anything else than ImageView, but as far as I know, the attachment is by default positioned at the right corner, as a miniature.

I am interested if you find additional informations.

Here is the great links that helped me build my Notification Feature in my App.

**Sources:**

[Rich Notification Guide](https://github.com/pluralsight/guides/blob/master/published/swift/creating-ios-rich-push-notifications/article.md)

[Notification with Attachment](https://medium.com/@tsif/ios-10-rich-push-notifications-with-media-attachments-a54dc86586c2)

**PS:**  I am also sad and disapointed that the expended view only appears with 3D Touch (People don't use it, 3D Touch is a failure to me).

Comment: swiping left, and tapping view opens it too.. I was ranting about 3D touch too, but I used to it now.. I've seen those resources too.. Your first sentence in the answer summarizes my knowledge - but I would like to by 100% sure - even a speaker at WWDC presentation would just mention it by the way, it would be nice.

Comment: Yeah, we are at the same level of knowledge concerning Rich Notifications then. I can't help you more. I don't have the swiping left feature on iPhone 7, but on iPhone 7 Plus I do. Strange ? And even if I am used to the 3D Touch, the issue is that the majority of user, Mr Lamba will not know about 3D touch, except if you teach your user...
**EDIT:** I have your features on the notification pannel, but not directly when I receive the notification as a banner.